# How can I load NAN libraries with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

How can I load [NAN](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) libraries with Meteor? Currently, I'm using this code:

```
greenworks = require('./imports/lib/lib/greenworks-osx64');
```

When I try to load a ".node" file, Meteor errors with this:

```
Error: Cannot find module './imports/lib/lib/greenworks-osx64'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
  at meteorInstall.imports.lib.greenworks.js (imports/lib/greenworks.js:13:25)
  at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
  at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
  at meteorInstall.imports.lib.theculling.js (imports/lib/theculling.js:1:18)
  at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
  at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
  at Module.Mp.import (/Users/jmeyer2k/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.7.5.8vojen++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime.js:70:16)
  at meteorInstall.server.main.js (server/main.js:1:1)
```

What I've tried already: changing the path to different relative and absolute paths; [checking code for references to ".js"](https://github.com/benjamn/install/blob/master/install.js#L6)

Comment: Error: Cannot find module './imports/lib/lib/greenworks-osx64'
It look like there is error in your path

Comment: Has the package been posted on https://atmospherejs.com/ ? If not, you can publish it there: https://atmospherejs.com/i/publishing Otherwise it seems you need to install it in the proper directory in order for meteor to find it...